# Is it possible to not use libcinder's default app class?

Tags: c++, game-engine, glfw, cinder

I am helping to start a new oss project, and want more flexibility than libcinder's default app class gives me, is there a way that I could use Cinder, but not use the default app class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using Cinder outside of its own OpenGL context is very difficult to setup and is probably not worth the effort involved.

However, you can deconstruct the CINDER_APP macro, albeit it will no longer be cross-platform unless you do that yourself.

example:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    ---extra code----

    cinder::app::RendererRef renderer(new RendererGl());
    cinder::app::AppMsw::main<imageApp>(renderer, "imageApp", &imageApp::prepareSettings);
    return 0;
}
```